# Does a field being named "value" have any special semantics?

Tags: influxdb

Examples in the InfluxDB documentation usually include a field named `value`. For instance, https://docs.influxdata.com/influxdb/v1.4/write_protocols/line_protocol_reference/#examples contains many example inserts that all include a `value` field, such as:

```
INSERT mymeas value=1.0
```

Is this use of `value` just a convention, or is there some special behaviour associated with the name `value`? I know that inserts without a `value` field are legal and that I can query for them with `select` queries just like rows with a `value`, but I don't know whether there's some special handling of `value`s hidden under the surface that I'm not noticing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The use of `value` as field name appears to just be a convention in the documentation. Neither the query language spec for [identifiers](https://docs.influxdata.com/influxdb/v1.4/query_language/spec/#identifiers) or [field keys](https://docs.influxdata.com/influxdb/v1.4/concepts/glossary/#field-key) mention anything about it (and `value` is not a [keyword](https://docs.influxdata.com/influxdb/v1.4/query_language/spec/#keywords)).

Comment: This was my conclusion as well. I'll accept this, and if we've missed something, I'll leave it to future readers to contradict you.